# JQuery - change and keypress events are giving different results

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have a strange behaviour of a keypress event.

I have a script that removes the space before a comma and adds a space after the comma.

```
$("#answer").keypress(function () {
  this.value = $.map(this.value.split(","), $.trim).join(", ");
});
```

It works as expected if I use a change event method.

[image]

However, if I use keypress, then it works fine with the commas, but it starts removing the spaces between the words.

[image]

Also, tried with different events: `input, click, keyup, keydown`... but the behaviour is the same.

I have tried to find if anyone had this issue, but I can't seem to find anything.
Any idea what might be wrong? Or maybe it is somehow conflicting with another script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `change` event will be triggered only when you de-focus the input. In contrast, the `keypress` event will be triggered after you've pressed the key, but before the key press has resulted in the value of the element being changed - this is why you can call `event.preventDefault` inside a `keypress` event to prevent the typed character from making its way to the input:

```js
$("#answer").keyup(function () {
  console.log('keypress: "' + this.value + '"');
});
$("#answer").change(function () {
  console.log('change: "' + this.value + '"');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="answer"></textarea>
```

A `keyup` event will run *after* the input's value has been changed.

When someone is typing, there will often be a trailing space at the end, when they're preparing for another word. When you have a listener that runs every time someone types a key, if the trailing space exists, it'll be removed by the `$.trim` method.

Consider using a regular expression instead: match `\s*,\s*` (to match zero or more spaces, followed by a comma, followed by zero or more spaces), then replace with a comma followed by a space:

```js
$("#answer").on('keyup', function () {
  this.value = this.value.replace(/\s*,\s*/g, ', ');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="answer"></textarea>
```

Comment: That did it. Thank you. That makes sense!

Answer (score 1):

**keypress**

The `keypress` event is sent to an element when the browser registers keyboard input. So, when you type something like "abc" and then put a space after it `keypress` event will be triggered and then `this.value.split(",")` will result in `["abc "]` but you running trim after it. So, actuall result is like:

```
'abc '.split(',').map(x=>x.trim()).join(', ') //=> 'abc'
```

Thus all the spaces are removed during `keypress` event.

**change**

The change event is sent to an element when its value changes. For select boxes, checkboxes, and radio buttons, the event is fired immediately when the user makes a selection with the mouse, but for the other element types the event is deferred until the element loses focus.

So, the value never waits for any particualr keyboard input and you a simple behaviour like:

```
'abc def,abc def'.split(',').map(x=>x.trim()).join(', ') 
//=> 'abc def, abc def'
```